# Passing params when manually calling manage command

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass the '--noinput' parameter to a command:

```
rebuild_index.Command().handle()
```

But it is not working:

```
File "/Users/XXX/Projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/clear_index.py", line 38, in handle
    yes_or_no = six.moves.input("Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

So I have tried, which still gives the same error:

```
rebuild_index.Command().handle(verbosity=1)
```

Calling the update_index command in the same manner (no args) works fine, how do I pass parameters to the handler manually?

Answer (score 1):

Ok the answer was:

```
rebuild_index.Command().handle(interactive=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by piping

`rebuild_index <<< $'yes'`  if yes

`rebuild_index <<< $'no'`  if no